# Immediate update to JCombobox in Java

Tags: java, mysql, sql, swing, jcombobox

A person wishes to add a NEW Job to the database. A `Combobox` list the existing employers already in the database for the new Job to be added against. But if an employer is not present customers have the option click on a button to add an employer. Once added that employer should immediately be displayed in the textfield.

I am trying to achieve the above scenario with my coding and mysql database, but cant think of the logic to do so...

Table Employer

```
CREATE TABLE "Employer" ("employerID" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY  NOT NULL ,
"name" CHAR,
"industry" CHAR,
"contact1" CHAR,
"contact2" CHAR,
"email" CHAR,
"website" CHAR,
"facts" CHAR,
"phone" VACHAR)
```

Table Job

```
CREATE TABLE "Job" ("jobID" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY  NOT NULL ,
"employerID" INTEGER,
"title" CHAR,
"description" CHAR,
"type" CHAR,"salary" CHAR,
"benefits" CHAR,
"vacancies" INTEGER,
"closing" CHAR,
"requirement" CHAR,
"placement" BOOL,
"applyTo" CHAR,
"status" CHAR,
"posted" CHAR, 
"location" CHAR)
```

Class Employer_GUI - Consist of a simple form and save button which saves new EMPLOYERS into `Employer` table

```
private void SaveEmpButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {

    try {
        String sql = "INSERT INTO Employer (name,industry,contact1,contact2,email,website,facts,phone) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
        pst = conn.prepareStatement(sql);

                    pst.setString(1, txtName.getText());
                    pst.setString(2, txtInd.getText());
                    pst.setString(3, txtC1.getText());
                    pst.setString(4, txtC2.getText());
                    pst.setString(5, txtEmail.getText());
                    pst.setString(6, txtWeb.getText());
                    pst.setString(7, txtFacts.getText());
                    pst.setString(8, txtPhone.getText());
                    pst.execute();
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, ""+txtName.getText()+" added to database!");
        this.setVisible(false);
    }

    catch (Exception e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, ""+txtName.getText()+" could not be added!");
    }
    finally {
       try {
        rs.close(); pst.close();  }
         catch(Exception e) { } }  

}
```

//Class Job_GUI - Consist of a FORM to add JOBS only to `Job` table

```
private void fillCombo() {
    try {
        String sql = "SELECT * FROM Employer";
        pst = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
        rs = pst.executeQuery();

        while(rs.next()) {
            String empName = rs.getString("name");
            comboEmployer.addItem(empName);

        }
    }
```

How could the `JComboBox` `comboEmployer` be immediately have the selected item as the new Employer name just added?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood you want the new employee that was added to be what is selected in the combobox?

Once you have got the new employees name and added it to combobox, simply call [`JComboBox#setSelectedItem(Object o)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JComboBox.html#setSelectedItem%28java.lang.Object%29) with the name of the new employee.

i.e:

```
String newEmpName=...;
//code to add new employee goes here
//code to fill combobox with update values goes here
//now we set the selecteditem of the combobox
comboEmployer.setSelectedItem(newEmpName);
```

**UPDATE**

As per your comments:

The basics:

1) Get new employee name or whatever identifier matches that of the items in your combobox from your add employee dialog.

2) Than simply call `setSelectedItem(name) after the data has been added to`combobox`.

So you might see your *Add Employer* dialog return a name or have a method to get the name which was added to the database. In your combobox class after dialog is closed, you would refresh the combobox with new entries, get the name added via the add employee dialog and call `JComboBox#setSelectedItem(..)` with the name we got from *Add employer* dialog using getters or static variable

i.e:

```
class SomeClass {

    JFrame f=...;
    JComboBox cb=new ...;

    ...

    public void someMethod() {
       AddEmployerDialog addEmpDialog=new AddEmployerDialog(f);//wont return until exited or new name added

       String nameAdded=addEmpDialog.getRecentName();//get the name that was added

      //clear combobox of all old entries
      DefaultComboBoxModel theModel = (DefaultComboBoxModel)cb.getModel();
      theModel.removeAllElements();

       //refresh combobox with the latest names from db
       fillCombo();

       //now we set the selected item of combobox with the new name that was added
       cb.setSelectedItem(nameAdded);
  }

}

class AddEmployerDialog {

    private JDialog dialog;
    private String empName;//emp name will be assigned when save is pressed or whatever

    public AddEmployerDialog(JFrame frame) {

        dialog=new JDialog(f);
        dialog.setDefaultCloseOperation(JDialog.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        dialog.setModal(true);//so that we dont return control until exited or done
        //add components etc
        dialog.pack();
        dialog.setVisible(true);

    }

    public String getRecentName() {
        return empName;
    }

}
```

Comment: I think your code assumes `JCombobox` is in the same class, its not its in another GUI and there are database concepts to as the new employer is instantly added to database.

Comment: @MuminAli that doesnt matter what matters is the logic, from there you may have to pass variables, use static variables or getters and setters to retrieve the information you need to set the selected employee in the combobox or even create a method inside the combobox class that accepts a string and allows you to call it and it will set the selected item as that string, whatever best meets your needs, but I'd just make my class which adds new employees return the name of the latest added entry?

Comment: Il try getters and setters, but will it update while GUI is still visible? meaning live.

Comment: @MuminAli it should if not call `repaint()` on its instance... or `revalidate()` and `repaint()` but i dont think that will be necessary

Comment: `repaint()` would refresh and remove all contents from other textboxes? see below screenshot.

Comment: does your solution above take into account the relational database aspect in that the combobox value must relate to the new database entity > between Job.employerID and Employer.employerID.

Comment: @MuminAli As I said only if it doesnt update call repaint on combobox ONLY. And why should it take that into account that was not your question as I understood it *Once added that employer should immediately be displayed in the textfield.* and by texfiled I took it you meant combobox? we have added the new employee now we are simply getting the combobox to go to the new employee name which we do by calling `setSelectedItem(...)` and passing the name/data we want to be shown as the selectedItem

Comment: Looked at your update, I understand the logic, but there is some event handling issues at detecting when the add employer frame is closed and passing the value to the other class. If you can kindly support your answer with an example code. thanks

Comment: thankyou thank you :) associated a dialog with Job class instead of with a new class AddEmployer. It worked! tbh I didnt need the Employer class.

Comment: Any idea how to obtain the employer idea from the selected employer in combobox?

Comment: @MuminAli that would completely depend on your applications layout, a simple one just query the db with the name for the ID

Comment: if i use a select * from Employer where name=combobox.selectedItem.toString()... to obtain the id isit a bad practice?