# INSERT INTO USING INNER JOIN in Java

Tags: java, mysql, sql, database, sqlite

Table Employer

```
CREATE TABLE "Employer" ("employerID" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY  NOT NULL ,
"name" CHAR,
"industry" CHAR,
"contact1" CHAR,
"contact2" CHAR,
"email" CHAR,
"website" CHAR,
"facts" CHAR,
"phone" VACHAR)
```

Table Job

```
CREATE TABLE "Job" ("jobID" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY  NOT NULL ,
"employerID" INTEGER,
"title" CHAR,
"description" CHAR,
"type" CHAR,"salary" CHAR,
"benefits" CHAR,
"vacancies" INTEGER,
"closing" CHAR,
"requirement" CHAR,
"placement" BOOL,
"applyTo" CHAR,
"status" CHAR,
"posted" CHAR, 
"location" CHAR)

 try {  
    //String sqlStm = "INSERT INTO Job (employerID,title,description,type,salary,benefits,vacancies,closing,requirement,placement,applyTo,status,posted,location) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?) INNER JOIN Employer ON Job.employerID = Employer.employerID"; 
   String sqlStm = "SET @SELECTED_ID = (SELECT employerID FROM Employer WHERE name = '"+comboEmployer.getSelectedItem().toString()+"') INSERT INTO Job (employerID,title,description,type,salary,benefits,vacancies,closing,requirement,placement,applyTo,status,posted,location)VALUES (@SELECTED_ID,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
       pst = conn.prepareStatement(sqlStm);

    pst.setString(2,txtTitle.getText());
     pst.setString(3,areaDescription.getText());
      pst.setString(4,comboType.getSelectedItem().toString());
       pst.setString(5,txtSalary.getText());
        pst.setString(6,areaBenefits.getText());
         pst.setString(7,txtVac.getText());
          pst.setString(8,txtDate.getDateFormatString().toString());
           pst.setString(9,areaReq.getText());
            pst.setString(10,comboPlace.getSelectedItem().toString());
             pst.setString(11,txtWeb.getText());
              pst.setString(12,comboStatus.getSelectedItem().toString());
               pst.setString(13,"01-01-2013");
                pst.setString(14,txtLoc.getText());
                   pst.executeUpdate();
   } catch (Exception e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,e);
    } finally {
        try {
            rs.close();
            pst.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
    }  
}
```

I am trying to allow users to add jobs to the system and a form requires them to pick employers from `Employer` table. I am not sure how to relate the chosen employer from `JCombobox` to the Job. i.e. employerID in `Job` table should be matched to the employerID of `employer` table. Ive managed to do the `Select` statement,

```
 sql = "SELECT Job.jobID as 'Job ID', Employer.name as'Company', Job.title as 'Role', Job.type as 'Type', Job.closing as 'Closing Date' FROM Job INNER JOIN Employer ON Job.employerID=Employer.employerID ORDER BY Employer.name";
```

but not sure how to `INSERT` into sqlite manager. Heres the form : [image]

Comment: Why do you have an INNER JOIN in your INSERT query?  Also, are you using MySQL or SQLite (you included both tags)?

Comment: @PinnyM it is a relational database, i.e the employerID in Job table is the foreign key, and is primary key of Employer Table.

Comment: sqlite, but the statement could be similar in both instances

Comment: Can you find a source that lists INSERT INTO ... VALUES (...) INNER JOIN ... as a valid syntax for SQLite?  It doesn't appear to be valid [from here](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_insert.html).  And I'm not even sure what it would mean if it were valid, for that matter - can you clarify this point?  Typically an INSERT with VALUES is entirely under _your control_ and should not need any JOINs at all...

Comment: @PinnyM I am new to Inner Joins. I just want to achieve a relation between employer in employeers table and the employerID in Job table but not sure how to. was successful with the select statement, but not inserting.

maybe have to use SELECT DISTINCT?

Comment: These relations should be configured in your database schema via foreign keys, and in the ORM configuration (if you use one).  The only thing you need to do when inserting is to ensure that you use values that won't break the foreign key constraints.  In this case, you should have a way to determine in advance that the employerId you are going to pass matches a valid employer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `JComboBox` should contain objects of type `Employer`. This Employer class should, at least contain the ID of the employer (to be able to uniquely identify him), and the name of the employer (to display it in the combo box).

To insert a new Job, simply get the selected Employer from your combo box, get its ID, and pass it to your query (which should not have any inner join):

```
insert into job (employerID,title, ...) values (?, ?, ...)
```

Comment: I am not sure if my combox has that object and is able to give me the ID. I did it like this here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14171600/immediate-update-to-jcombobox-in-java

can you support your answer with an example code

Comment: how do i obtain the id from combobox, any help?

Comment: Read the swing tutorial about combo boxes: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/combobox.html. To get the ID of the selected employee, you would simply do `((Employee) comboBox.getSelectedItem()).getId()`

Answer (score 0):

You can handle it from the front-end coding itself. Combobox has two things - Value and Text. ComboBox item's value should be Job id and text should be Description. Use your `Select` query to retrieve this part. Then you can insert the value of the Selected option. Hence Job id will be inserted.

Comment: @TechBytes this is not my question. My question is how to link employerID in Employers table to employerID in job table when it comes to Inserting values.

Comment: And no a ComboBox entry doesn't have a value and a text. It only have elements and the eements can be any object. In this case, the type of the object should be `Employer`.

Answer (score 0):

I think I understand what you are trying to do.  You are trying to add to the 'Job' table using the values inputted on the form.  Since the drop-down box for employer is in text form and the 'Employer' table only accepts the employer ID, you would like something that would translate the employer name to the employer ID.

Give this code a try.  It's written in vanilla SQL so you might have to make some minor adjustments for SQLite

```
SET @SELECTED_ID = (SELECT employerID
                   FROM Employer
                   WHERE name = @your_text_box_variable)

INSERT INTO Job (employerID,title,description,type,salary,benefits,vacancies,closing,requirement,placement,applyTo,status,posted,location) 
VALUES (@SELECTED_ID,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)
```

Essentially, we are taking the value of the employer name taken from the form(transmitted using the variable @your_text_box_variable) and pulling back the employer ID associated with that name.  We can then use this employer ID to insert into the 'Job' table.

Comment: Bad bad bad solution. What if two employers have the same name? The type of the objects in the combo box should be Employer, and the OP should just get the ID from the selected employer and pass it to the query.

Comment: see this for combobox which I did http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14171600/immediate-update-to-jcombobox-in-java

Comment: @JBNizet, I don't think anybody would consciously design a drop-down box with two identical values

Comment: So based on the code on the other page, you want to replace the @your_text_box_variable with the object 'comboEmployer'

Comment: @LloydBanks: that's why we use primary keys: to make sure values are unique. If you don't use them to populate your combo box, you can't be sure that two employers won't have the same name. Even if that's not likely, primary keys are what you should use to identify a row in a database.

Comment: @JBNizet I have no idea why you brought up primary keys here.  I don't think this has anything to do with the situation at hand; except maybe just so you could respond even though there are no good reasons for you to respond

Comment: @LloydBanks: what do you think employerID is in the OP's question? It's the primary key of the employer of the job to create. Have you actually read the question? In a relational database, rows are identified by their PK. You may choose to identify them by a non unique other column if you like, but that will lead to bugs, additional complexity, and decreased performance. That's why it's bad design.

Comment: @JBNizet The OP didn't mention using the primary key to populate his drop-down menu.  In fact, if he did, he wouldn't have posted this question since it would have been pretty easy to obtain the employer ID if it was used to populate the list to begin with.  I think the most important thing about help sites like Stack is that we help others who are in particular situations, not tell them what we would have done had we built the system ourselves.  Maybe you should reread the original question, it might give you new insight into the author's original perspective

Comment: The key is that, to properly solve the problem (and not simply implement a dirty hack), the solution is to store employers in the combo box, and not employer names. I prefer giving good solutions rather than dirty hacks to posters. And that's probably why my answer was accepted as so many of my answers are every day. I know how to answer a question, thank you.

Comment: @JBNizet You're answer was accepted because you happened to be logged in when the OP was on and was exchanging messages with him in real time